# How to map "egyptian" to "Egypt"?

Tags: stems

I am writing a Java program that includes mapping phrases to RDF resources (named entity recognition).
It fails in the case of "egyptian" and "Egypt". 
How can I map such cases automatically?

The Porter Stemmer does not change "egyptian" and WordNet only includes "Egypt" in the text but not as a direct link, which I cannot extract automatically:

```
Noun

    {09719888} <noun.person>[18] S: (n) Egyptian#1 (egyptian%1:18:00::) (a native or inhabitant of Egypt)
    {07002660} <noun.communication>[10] S: (n) Egyptian#2 (egyptian%1:10:00::) (the ancient and now extinct language of Egypt under the Pharaohs; written records date back to 3000 BC)

Adjective

    {02983014} <adj.pert>[01] S: (adj) Egyptian#1 (egyptian%3:01:00::) (of or relating to or characteristic of Egypt or its people or their language)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it is a programming question not a linguistics question.

Comment: Actually it is at the intersection of both. I need to find a linguistic method that achieves my goal and then find a library that supports that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option may be using a more aggressive stemmer. E.g., [Lancaster stemmer](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/stem/lancaster.html) with NLTK in Python:

```
In [7]: stemmer = nltk.stem.LancasterStemmer()

In [8]: stemmer.stem('egyptian')
Out[8]: 'egypt'
```